# find more than one word in same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query to generate a list of companies that have “prior to”  more than once in their names.

For Example:

```
Company Name
Ittal PLC (adz ll **prior to** 04/2012) (Z Amp C **prior to** 02/2009)
```

Comment: Hi.  Can you show us what you've tried so far?  Where have you run into difficulties?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select *
from Yourtable
where len([Company Name]) - len(replace([Company Name],'prior to','')) > 1
  and len([Company Name]) - len(replace([Company Name],'prior to','')) <> len('prior to')
```

- [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9db25/3)

Comment: I don't think this will work.  The OP wants to find [Company Name]s with more than one occurrence of "prior to".  The code above will return rows with just one occurrence.  You could replace > 1 to >= (LEN('prior to') * 2).  This would highlight where the text was replaced twice or more.  Of course @GordonLinoff's approach (using LIKE) would be much simpler.

Comment: @destination-data - fixed. Added demo as well

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to use `like`:

```
where CompanyName like '%prior to%prior to%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably implement this as a two-step process.

1) Find all records matching **prior to**.

E.g.

**SELECT** Company_name **FROM** COMPANY_TABLE **WHERE** Company_name **LIKE** '%prior to%'

2) Iterate through all the records and find only those that have 2 occurrences of the prior to substring (in whatever language you're using).